# Login form query error

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have created a register form on my website which should register users in a database called mayan_users but when I enter details in the form and submit it I get 'query error' appearing, can anybody see where i may have made a mistake? I have included the code below. thanks.

```
<?php
     include("dbconnect.php");
     $firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
     $lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
     $address=$_POST['address'];
     $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
     $emailaddress=$_POST['emailaddress'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $query = "select emailaddress FROM mayan_users  where emailaddress='$emailaddress'";
      $link = mysql_query($query);
     if (!$link) {
      die('query error');
     }
     $num=mysql_num_rows($link);
     if ($num>0){
      die('email already exists'); //email already taken
     }
     $query = "insert into mayan_users (firstname, lastname, address, postcode, emailaddress, password) values('$firstname','$lastname','$address','$postcode', '$emailaddress','$password')";
     $link = @ mysql_query($query);
     if (!$link) {
      die('table write error');
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Post the actual error. Also, please do not use mysql_ - it is being deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead. You need to parameterize your query so that it is not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: use mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_erorr());

Comment: general tip: never ever use "static" error messages. they're absolutely useless for debugging. mysql will tell you WHY it's throwing an error... ... `or die (mysql_error())` will help you figure this out on your own. Plus, read about up [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) before you get your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try with the following.,

**HTML Part :**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="register">
<table>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address</td><td><input type="text" name="address" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Postal Code</td><td><input type="text" name="postcode" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" name="emailaddress" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**PHP Part :**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$select_db = mysql_select_db("mayan",$con);
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
     $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
     $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
     $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
     $postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);
     $emailaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailaddress']);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

     $query = "select emailaddress FROM mayan_users where emailaddress='$emailaddress'";
     $link = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
     $num = mysql_num_rows($link);

     if ($num>0){
      echo 'Email already exists'; //email already taken
     }

     else {
     $insert_query = "insert into `mayan_users`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`address`,`postcode`,`emailaddress`,`password`) values('$firstname','$lastname','$address','$postcode','$emailaddress','$password')";
     $result = mysql_query($insert_query)or die(mysql_error());
     echo "Registered Successfully!";
     }
}
?>
```

**MySQL Table Structure :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mayan_users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emailaddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: There's no escaping or parameterization of the strings... no bueno.

Comment: @Nicarus This one is rough example to help question asked user to get rid of his current problem what he stated above.

Comment: hi, this seems good on the whole, but it is returning with an error 'Unknown column 'emailaddress' in 'field list'. i can not see where this error is though.

Comment: @JohnPeter - I understand, I think you at least owe the OP a disclaimer about it if you are going to post it in your answer.

Comment: i am appreciative of any help to be honest, and because this site is for a university project i'm don't have to be too worried about security and such as the site will never actually go live.

Comment: @Ben Not possible i'm 100% sure this will work i have already tested in my local server...

Comment: OP: There is only 1 place you reference the emailaddress column. Are you sure it is in the table with that name? @JohnPeter - How can you tell him that it is not possible he is getting an error??

Comment: just check your column name which you have created in table.,i have created `emailaddress` column name in table for my example.,so double check with this.

Comment: Also Just check with the above edits @Ben I'm working as a Team Lead For a PHP Developers in my company.,so don't worry i'm here to resolve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

At first, you need to be aware that your code is vunerable for SQL injections. The reason you get the 'query error' error could be the formatting of the input in the $_POST['emailaddress'] value.

Also make sure you do not store clear text passwords in the database. If the website/application gets hacked, you make it very easy for the hacker to gather passwords.

If you do not want the HTML stripped from the post data, remove the ipSafe functions.

I suggest you do this:
I've added some basic security. Please read in on the functions `mysql_real_escape_string` and `htmlspecialchars` on [www.php.net](http://php.net/).

```
$firstname = ipSafe($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = ipSafe($_POST['lastname']);
$address = ipSafe($_POST['address']);
$postcode = ipSafe($_POST['postcode']);
$emailaddress = ipSafe($_POST['emailaddress']);
$password = $_POST['password']; // please use encryption! :(

$sql = "
    SELECT `emailaddress`
    FROM `mayan_users`
    WHERE `emailaddress` = '".dbSafe($emailaddress)."'
    LIMIT 1;
";

if ( ($query = mysql_query($sql)) && (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) )
{
    $sqlinsert = "
        INSERT INTO `mayan_users`(
            `firstname`, 
            `lastname`, 
            `address`, 
            `postcode`, 
            `emailaddress`, 
            `password`
        )
        VALUES (
            '".dbSafe($firstname)."', 
            '".dbSafe($lastname)."', 
            '".dbSafe($address)."', 
            '".dbSafe($postcode)."', 
            '".dbSafe($emailaddress)."', 
            '".dbSafe($password)."'
        )
    ";

    if (mysql_query($sqlinsert))
    {
        print "User added.";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Something went wrong: ".mysql_error();
    }
}
else
{
    // email exists in database or error
    if (mysql_errno() > 0)
    {
        print "An error occured: ".mysql_error();
    }
}

function dbSafe ($string)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $string = stripslashes($string);
    }

    return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}

function ipSafe($string)
{
    return htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($string));
}
```

Comment: htmlspecialchars/striptags are useless for sql injection, and you should **NEVER** manipulate a string after you've done sql escaping on it. you risk undoing the escaping and re-opening an injection hole. so -1 for that. sql escaping is the **LAST** thing you do to a string before using it in a query.

Comment: I've noticed I switched the functions. I am aware of the functions, please review your comment.

Comment: no, you're still doing the equivalent of `$fn = ipSafe(dbSave(...))`

Comment: The order matters. The string gets `cleaned` of html and other unwanted characters first. When you put them in the database they are made safe for database input, thus sql-injection safe.

Comment: Yes, now I see you fixed the order. But you're assuming the OP wants html removed.

Comment: That's correct. Might be a bit too much, but in my opinion you do not want HTML in user data. For example; if the data is beeing viewed in some sort of admin page, and you print the first name, and the name contains <h1>'s or maybe even javascript (XSS!), it could mess up a lot of stuff.

Comment: and if someone's password happens to be `a<!\>567d@`? oops, now you've corrupted it.

Comment: Removed the ipSafe function from the password variable. Should not be there.

Comment: Why still use mysql_ and not PDO or mysqli_?

Comment: i wasn't worried about security for this particular website because it is a uni project and will never actual go live but thanks anyway.